# Regular expression for replacing string with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need help in writing regular expression:
part of my string is fixed and another part of its variable.

only if fixed AND variable string exist i need to alter the string other wise no.

Fixed string:example: AA.BBB.COM 
Variable string (may or mayn't exist ): US, but if exist it will be always two letter string with any combination of letter.

In below string if I have variable two letter string exist I want to append “.new”

```
1 ) https://XY**.US**.AA.BBB.COM
 Output:  https:// XYZ12**.US.NEW**.AA.BBB.COM

2 ) https://XY.UK.AA.BBB.COM
 Output:  https:// XYZ12.UK.NEW.AA.BBB.COM

3) https://XY.AA.BBB.COM  (no variable string so no change)
 Output:  https:// XY.AA.BBB.COM
```

Thanks for your help .
Raghav

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should get you started, there are other methods. Splitting and parsing might suit better depending on your real requirements:

```
var s = 'https://XY.US.AA.BBB.COM';
var t = 'https://XY.UK.AA.BBB.COM';
var u = 'https://XY.AA.BBB.COM';

var re = /(\.)(UK|US)(\.)/;

alert( 
  s.replace(re, '$1' + '$2' + '.NEW' + '$3') + '\n' +
  t.replace(re, '$1' + '$2' + '.NEW' + '$3') + '\n' +
  u.replace(re, '$1' + '$2' + '.NEW' + '$3')
 );
```